# Show next element if user types in the previous element

Tags: jquery

I am having five Textarea, but I want to show Textarea one by one as the user types into those. For example, only the 1st Textarea should be visible on page load, and 2-5 should be hidden. When the user types into the 1st Textarea, the 2nd should be visible, and 3-5 should be hidden. Again, when user types into 2nd Textarea then 3rd should be shown, and 4-5 should be still hidden and so on. I have written some jQuery for it, please have a look. (Also I am having 20 textarea like this, so I need a neat code with `this` selector if possible.)

```html
<textarea id="step1"></textarea>
<textarea id="step2"></textarea>
<textarea id="step3"></textarea>
<textarea id="step4"></textarea>
<textarea id="step5"></textarea>

<style>
#step2,#step3,#step4,#step5{display:none}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#step1').keyup(function(){ 
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) { 
        $('#step2').css("display","none");
    } 
    else { 
        $('#step2').css("display","block");
        }
}).keyup();
</script>
```

Comment: what happens if, for example the first 2 textareas was filled with input causing the third to appear and next the text in the first one gets deleted? such event should hide textbox #2 and #3 and erase their content?

Comment: If we delete text from first textarea and second textarea is already having some text then it should not 'display:none' the second textarea. It shoud do it when even second or further textarea are also empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a selector like this: `$('[id^=step]')` to fetch all elements having the id starting with `step` when adding them the keyup event handler.

But it would be at risk of returning false positives if the document accidentally contained elements having a similar id. Also `$('textarea[id^=step]')` wouldn't be strict enough in my opinion.

So also for the sake of having a better strategy I slightly modified the document so that each *step* element is actually a div container embedding a label and a textarea with the added benefit of having the evidence of which textarea you are seeing on screen watching the label next to it.

My demo adds the `keyup` event handler to each of those elements having the `step` class with the convention that their id should begin with the string `step` anyway and following a consecutive number.

Such event handler when triggered, will extract the number part of the id of the container triggering the event, and will fetch the container having the consecutive id next to it (+1). Such container will be hidden or shown based on the condition if the current textarea contains text AND the next textarea doesn't.

I'm not perfectly sure I totally understood that point though, feel free to correct me with details on where and why I might be wrong

```js
$('.step textarea').keyup(function() {      
  const id = $(this).closest('.step').prop('id');
  const idMatch = /step(\d+)/im.exec(id);    
  if (idMatch != null) {
    const idNext = parseInt(idMatch[1])+1;       
    const nextStep = $(`#step${idNext} textarea`);      
    if(nextStep.length){
      if ($(this).val().length == 0 && $(nextStep).val().length == 0) {    
        $(`#step${idNext}`).css("display", "none");
      } else {
        $(`#step${idNext}`).css("display", "block");
      }
    }
  }    
})
```

```css
#step2,
#step3,
#step4,
#step5 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="step1" class="step">
  <label>step1</label>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div id="step2" class="step">
  <label>step2</label>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div id="step3" class="step">
  <label>step3</label>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div id="step4" class="step">
  <label>step4</label>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div id="step5" class="step">
  <label>step5</label>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This example is working good as expected but there is one problem, when we type in textarea 5 and then delete typed text from textarea 5 then it gives some error.

Comment: I forgot to check if the next element existed... so the last _step_ in the chain was trying to fetch the value from #step6 despite it not existing.. I corrected that part adding a condition `.length` before performing the action